# Open (NOT IMPORT) Excel file with R script

Tags: r, excel

I would like to open **(NOT IMPORT)** excel file with R script.

R script creates dataset which has to be showed as a dashboard in Excel. Excel imports dataset with VBA, creates dashboard and is emailing it to end users.

I am aware that I can execcute R script from VBA (but in this case I do not know when R script finishes, so I am not interested in this option)
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
browseURL("path/to/your/file")
```